# Which Magento Version is Suitable Based on Size of Business and Performance

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, javascript, php-7, magento2.3.7

I have used the Magento versions 1.7-1.9 in the past, and now I've got back into starting a new e-commerce business again. I like Magento the best because the code layout is really smooth for SEO, and the cleanest to present to Google. I like the control you have over the product Urls and category URLS.  In my opinion, Magento website rank better than wordpress websites, and other CMS platforms. This is just off the experience I have with these platforms.     I have 1and1 hosting, which doesn't really have the best Magento setup, but I do like that the people in chat are willing to help set stuff that I cannot actually activate.  Imagick-7.4 had to be manually added by support.   I have Magento version 2.3.7 and I really don't like the performance of it so far in the backend. Things are running really slow.   I don't have everything set up yet; still installing the theme, and images. Then I have to add all the products.      So far the performance of Magento 1 is better than the performance of Magento 2 and functionality so far since I've been using this software.  Always looking to learn the best ways to optimize and give Magento 2 a second chance, which is what I'm doing before I actually revert back and use Magento 1.9 version which is the best version Magento has had out.  Less problems, less work.

**I'd like this from experts** that use the **Magento repositories** a lot. I'm sure there's **pros and cons in both versions**. But for an *honest*, and **expert opinion** from someone here. What would they recommend ? Magento version for a small e-commerce website ran by just one person generating over $200,000 a year in revenue with less than 250 products and over 2,000 visitors a day.  Do you think Magento 1 would be better in this scenario?   I just think the Magento 2 version is for larger companies that have multiple employees, lots of products, and layered navigation attributes where there's more resources being used, so Magento 2 would higher a powerful compute of data.   Well I'm not the big company, I'm just the 1 person with less than 250 products.  This is a very important decision as Magento is the only e-commerce solution on my radar.  I don't like Shopify, nor do I like Wordpress's Woocommerce.   (Google isn't fond of Woocommerce).  It all comes down to selecting the best Magento version.  I want to select and commit to the one that has the best compatibility, and performance. With no errors, and bugs that develop from the resources that load on the server.    So what do you guys think???

Comment: If you want performance and no bugs Magento is not the platform for you, out the box it is slow and has bugs so it's an uphill battle

Answer (score 1):

I work at a startup that's been using Magento 1 since 2014. If you are an individual person with limited funds and can't afford high-end servers, Magento 1 is your best choice. Not only is it highly customizable, but there's also plenty of extensions for your needs. However, Magento 1.9 reached its End-Of-Life last year and it no longer receives any bug fixes or security patches. For that reason, I recommend to use [OpenMage](https://openmage.org), a free open-source fork of Magento 1 backed by community contributors (including me) and It still receives bug fixes, security patches, performance improvements and even new features occasionally not to mention it also supports newer versions of PHP including PHP 8! I recommend using their latest v1.9 release. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For your type of business would say Magento 2.4.x is good and no need to go for its enterprise commerce version.

You just have 250 products and just 2000 visitors so this can be easily taken care by Magento community module.

You need to make sure that your setup has been done rightly:

1. varnish is a must.
2. While its Varnish no blocks should have cachable as false.
3. Make sure extensions developed are taking care of and effectively using cache.
4. Theme uses JS judiciously and JS are placed at right place.